# Packet capture tools for Nokia N8 (symbian ^3) Phones

Tags: symbian, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, nokia-n8

Are there any packet capture tools (like tcpdump and wireshark) for Nokia N8/ symbian ^3 phones! I am currently working on my thesis and have almost done with the application layer behavior using JavaScript but am required to study the network behavior of HTML5 web applications on symbian phones.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app available at betalabs.nokia.com called Nokia Connectivity Analyzer:

http://betalabs.nokia.com/apps/nokia-connectivity-analyzer

I have not tried this part of it, but the "Connection Observer" component claims it can do ip packet capture.

Answer (score 0):

The Symbian browser is based on Webkit

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your response, but not quite the answer I was looking for. I mean, are there any packet capture tools for symbian ^3 phones like tcpdump and wireshark in desktop?